# CROSS JOIN filter

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports, cross-join

I need to 'manufacture' records for a query, but at the same time, restrict the list of values that are returned from a 'lookup' table.

Is there a way to use 'filter' a CROSS JOIN without having to resort to using an in-line view?

This syntax works as expected (I get the desired results):

```
SELECT  E.ID,  
        M.VALUE,
        MT.ID, MT.NAME

FROM    ENCOUNTER E
CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT  ID, NAME
      FROM    MEASUREMENT_TYPE
      WHERE   ID IN ('6941','6946')
) MT
LEFT OUTER JOIN MEASURE M ON E.ID=M.ENCOUNTER_ID
        AND MT.ID=M.MEASURE_TYPE_ID
```

Unfortunately, if I use this approach, I need to use a Command object with Crystal Reports rather than its native 'Visual Linking Expert'.  Command objects irritate me.

Adding a filter to the WHERE clause results in an equal join, which is undesirable in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  E.ID,  
  M.VALUE,
  MT.ID,
  MT.NAME
FROM
  ENCOUNTER         AS E
CROSS JOIN
  MEASUREMENT_TYPE  AS MT
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  MEASURE           AS M
    ON  E.ID  = M.ENCOUNTER_ID
    AND MT.ID = M.MEASURE_TYPE_ID
WHERE
  MT.ID IN ('6941','6946')
```

In this case you *can* put the filter in the WHERE clause because it's a LEFT JOIN and you're filtering the *left* side of the query.

If you were filtering the `Measure` table, the filter would have had to go in the `LEFT JOIN`'s ON clause.

An additional alternative is to `INNER JOIN` instead of `CROSS JOIN` and use the filter there.  This is because the ON clause doesn't actually *need* to reference both tables...

```
  ENCOUNTER         AS E
INNER JOIN
  MEASUREMENT_TYPE  AS MT
    ON MT.ID IN ('6941','6946')
```

Comment: That's invalid SQL. The `[` and `]` are illegal characters in a SQL identifier.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Silly Oracle, that always trips me up, and I never ever learn.  But I do love those `[]` so :(

Comment: You answer was selected as it was the only one that could be (nearly) implemented in Crystal Reports.

Comment: @Dems: that's not silly Oracle. That's the what SQL standard says (and SQL Server is the only DBMS that accepts this strange notation)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, an `inner join` would do the same as your `cross join`.  Replace:

```
CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT  ID, NAME
      FROM    MEASUREMENT_TYPE
      WHERE   ID IN ('6941','6946')
) MT
```

with

```
INNER JOIN MEASUREMENT_TYPE MT ON MT.ID IN ('6941','6946')
```